# Combine Multiple Query with one standart column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I using MySQL, I have 2 Query Select SQL, first Query will return Result A, and second will return Result B, so i want to combine that two Query Result, ID column of Result A and value_num of Result B become standard Column, and i don't think for use subselect because i have tried that and it will take long time effort in query process , how can i do this ?

**Result A :**

```
+------------+--------------+
+  ID        +  Name        +
+------------+--------------+
+   1        +  Steve       +
+   2        +  Mile        +
+   3        +  Santo       +
+   4        +  Del Piero   +
+   5        +  Jack        +
============================+
```

**Result B :**

```
+------------+--------------+
+  Valuenum  +  value       +
+------------+--------------+
+   1        +      20      +
+   2        +      30      +
+   6        +      44      +
+   7        +      55      +
============================+
```

**Combine Result A dan Result B, below is my expect output.**

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
+ID_valuenum +  Name        + value    +
+------------+--------------+----------+
+   1        +  Steve       + 20       +
+   2        +  Mile        + 30       +
+   3        +  Santo       + Null     +
+   4        +  Del Piero   + Null     +
+   5        +  Jack        + Null     +
+   6        +  Null        + 44       +
+   7        +  Null        + 55       +
============================+==========+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  ta.Id as ID_Valuenume
  ,ta.name
  ,tb.value
from TableA ta
left join TableB tb on ta.ID=tb.valuenum
union
select
  tb.valuenum
  ,ta.name
  ,tb.value
from TableB tb
left join TableA ta on ta.ID=tb.valuenum
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for this :

```
 select ra.ID as ID_valuenum,
        ra.Name,rb.value from ResultA ra left join ResultB rb on ra.ID=rb.Valuenum 

        UNION

        select rb.Valuenum,null as Name,rb.value from ResultB where rb.Valuenum not in 
    (select ID from ResultB)
```

->In first part you have to use Left Join so it will give you data

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
+ID_valuenum +  Name        + value    +
+------------+--------------+----------+
+   1        +  Steve       + 20       +
+   2        +  Mile        + 30       +
+   3        +  Santo       + Null     +
+   4        +  Del Piero   + Null     +
+   5        +  Jack        + Null     +
```

->In second part its not required to use any join then it will give data:-

```
+   6        +  Null        + 44       +
+   7        +  Null        + 55       +
```